# Power Query - Alternative for Join to filter Records

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have two tables:

1. Table: One Row per Order with the Status (Online / Offline)
2. Table: Multiple Rows per Order

Now I would like to reduce the number of record/ rows in the second table based on the status (Offline) from Table 1.

Is there any alternative to a right join? The first table is filtered on Status 'Offline'
We are talking about several millions of rows which takes some time to Join.

Any thoughts on this from your sight?

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

- Create a relationship between these two tables and filter to "Offline".
- You could create a join (Merge queries) in Power query and only select the On/Off State column to append. Then the import needs more time, but you're getting a flat dataset in PowerBI
- Create a new column in PowerBI with DAX and use `LOOKUPVALUE`

Without seeing the data I think I would try the first one. If it's too slow, the I think the only way is the second point. Even it takes some more time for importing.
The third one might be the slowest.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Option 1 and 3 will not work since I need to do this step in Power Query.

Comment: Ok, then I think there is only way 2 if you dont have the option to do it before (SQL DB or where the data comes from).

Comment: But I think power query should be able to handle it. I'm also having files with millions of rows and multiple Merges in Power Query an it works quite well. Even it takes 1 -2 mins for updating.